# Upscale small images in fancybox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Is there a way to upscale images that are smaller than the viewport in fancybox2? I want them to fit all the space horizontally or vertically that's available (obviously keeping the aspect ratio).

I know this will cause the images to become blurry, but I need this behaviour.

Thanks

Comment: You might be looking for http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful ==No. 13 (just set `aspectRatio : true`) http://jsfiddle.net/tg7h0pfy/